# White list specific params to cover possible vulnerabilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I am trying to find a way to whitelist certain params in order to prevent the ability for these params to be manipulated into dangerous data.

I have ran brakeman on my app and it specifically highlights the lines:

```
new_entity_model = new_entity_type.camelize.constantize
```

and

```
new_entity_type_num = new_entity_type.upcase.constantize
```

Entity type and entity id are attriubutes in the home table.

```
  def create_reassign_entity
    @house=House.find(params[:id])
    new_entity_id = params[:house].try(:[], :entity_id).presence
    new_entity_type = params[:house].try(:[], :entity_type).presence

    if new_entity_id.blank? || new_entity_type.blank?
      flash[:error] = t('Please_select_an_entity')
    else
      new_entity_model = new_entity_type.camelize.constantize
      new_entity_type_num = new_entity_type.upcase.constantize
      new_entity = new_entity_model.find_cached(new_entity_id) rescue nil
      if new_entity.is_a?(new_entity_model)
        @house.update_attributes(entity_id: new_entity_id, entity_type: new_entity_type_num)
        @house.update_entity_state_county
        flash[:notice] = t('This_house_will_be_reassigned_to_entity_') + new_entity.to_label
      else
        flash[:error] = t('Unable_to_find')
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(house_path(@house)) }
      format.json { render json: @house, status: :ok }
      format.xml  { render xml: @house.as_json, status: :ok }
    end
  end
```

```
Confidence: High
Category: Remote Code Execution
Check: UnsafeReflection
Message: Unsafe reflection method `constantize` called on parameter value
Code: params[:home][:entity_type].camelize.constantize
File: app/controllers/houses_controller.rb
Line: 113
```

If any other information is needed in order to get a bigger picture I'm happy to help.

Comment: I wonder what you later do with those values or classes? Calling `constantize` on a value that was provided by a user is one thing. But actually doing something and potentially calling other methods on those class is another. Would you mind providing the whole controller action and make your use-case more clear?

Comment: Question has just been updated.

Comment: It looks like you are using [STI](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). Can you list the models types that are allowed to be associated as entity? Is `belongs_to :entity` optional on the `House` model?

Comment: On a side note `rescue nil` creates a black hole that swallows any type of exception - including the very low level ones your application should not rescue. Do not do that. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/don-t-inline-rescue-in-ruby

Comment: @spickermann, there is no relationship to the entity set up in the model.  The house table has an entity_type and entity_id field within it.

Comment: That then leads to the question - why isn't there an association set up? Is this legacy code that you have inherited?

Comment: If there is not fixed relationship, does that mean that users could just send anything, for example `entity_type = 'User'` and `entity_id = 1` and it might work if there is a `User` model?

Comment: Yes, correct. Technically someone could just guess a correct value.

Comment: @max, I'm not sure. The code used here is very old. Almost 10 years!

Comment: Then you have your reason, why Brakeman complains about this `UnsafeReflection` and why it should be fixed. First step: Collect a list of all allowed `entity_type` names.

Comment: Ok, so collect the relevant entity_types and basically whitelist them I assume?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem can be solved using nested attributes, use nested attributes.

If you really need to go this way, you can sanitize the params like this:

```rb
allowed_classes = {"house" => House, "room" => Room}
class_name = params[:home].try(:[], :entity_type).downcase
entity = allowed_classes[class_name].new
```

You should handle `allowed_classes[class_name].nil?` with some kind of error 400.

Comment: If you're not stuck on an ancient versions of Rails use `class_name = params.dig(:home, :entity)&.classify`.

Comment: @max My answer was posted before we saw the full code, which implies this is probably a polymorphic has_many association to which I would just pass any string from the user (maybe with `classify`) and let the model validate if it is an acceptable class for the association.